# Which blocks more damage, Antagonist or Blockade? And by how much?

Tags: borderlands-2

The [Antagonist](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Antagonist) Seraph shield explicitly states its Damage Reduction on the card (49% maximum, I believe, with the right parts). The [Blockade](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Blockade) does not explicitly state its Damage Resistance on the card, but [the Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Borderlands_Wiki) gives at least one specific value:

> The resistance effect is currently bugged, and is equal to up to 38% (depending on the shield's parts and level) independently of shield charge, even when the shield is depleted.

http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Blockade

Damage Reduction is potentially different from Damage Resistance. I imagine Damage Reduction is straightforward, but I cannot find any formula for Damage Resistance. So, which blocks more damage in the end? And if the Antagonist blocks more damage, is it better than the Blockade?

Answer (score 1):

The Blockade blocks more damage, when throwing Chain Lightning at my feet.

I recorded some values (and don't remember other conditions, like level):

```
Antagonist (Hyperion)   1827    →   1005 (822)
Blockade (Hyperion)     1403    →   710  (693)
Blockade (max cap.)     2420    →   1727 (693)
Blockade (1563 listed)  1799    →   1105 (694)
Blockade (1930 listed)  2166    →   1473 (693)
```

The Blockade seems to block the same amount of damage across different parts.  The Orphan Maker dealt the same amount of damage between both shields, so I don't think the Orphan Maker is suitable for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Antagonist blocks more.

According to the [wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Blockade) Blockade's damage resistance effect can be up to 38%.

And the [Antagonist wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Antagonist) shows an image of a level 61 shield with 49% damage reduction.

The percentage of damage reduction for both shields will increase with the shield's level.